# C function to exercise as many registers as possible

Tags: c++, c, assembly

I'm writing a test suite for an assembler stub on multiple CPU architectures. The stub is meant to pass arguments to a C callback.

I have written tests to cover multiple scenarios (eg passing struct by value, mixing arguments of different native size, mixing float args with ints etc) and I would now like the test callback to do *something* that will use up lots of registers/stack slots etc.

The idea is to try and flush out implementations that are only working by fluke (eg value not correctly put on stack, but it happens to still be in a certain register so you get away with it etc).

Can anyone recommend a good piece of C/C++ I can use as the test here? I realise register use varies wildly across architectures and there's no guarantee at all that it will get complete coverage, but it would be nice to have something that gave a *reasonable* amount of confidence. Thanks

Comment: I think that if you want to be sure that registers get used, you have to either know the compiler, or write assembler. Otherwise I believe it's a shot in the dark as the C standard really doesn't specify under what circumstances registers are to be used. Even the `register` keyword is only a _suggestion_ to the compiler (and these days, an optimizing compiler tends to know better anyway.)

Comment: maybe not 100% reliable, try declaring lots of `volatile` variables. If possible take a look at the generated code.

Comment: Just replace the callback with a function implemented in assembly language that clobbers all registers and returns.

Comment: I don't think a single function will work; SPARC register windows wouldn't expose all registers.

Comment: Many crypto/hash algorithms tend to use a lot of different registers by nature of having a lot of live variables at a time. Things like FFTs or other block transforms do too...

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in the C/C++ standards to help you here. Ultimately the only reliable way is exactly the way that compiler writers do it. They study the code their compiler generates and think up ways to break it.

Having said that, I can think of some strategies that might flush out some common problems.

1. Make calls with lots of different combinations of argument types and numbers. For example, a function with a single argument or return value that is a char/short/int/long/float/double/pointer etc will exercise a certain range of compiler code generation (and likely be passed in a register if possible). The same function with lots of arguments will use a different strategy, and (in most cases) not have enough registers.
2. Insert preamble code into the called function, so that passed in arguments are not used immediately but the registers get filled with other values.
3. Use variadic arguments. The calling conventions for variadic arguments (especially with separate compile and link) virtually guarantee arguments on the stack and not in registers.
4. Exercise lots of different call types: not just simple scalars but struct by value, pointer to function, pointer to member, etc.
5. Cheat. Call with one prototype but cast the function pointer so that the callee has a different prototype. For example, call with double on the stack but the callee function has two longs. Requires some inside knowledge of compiler workings.

The only pre-written code you will find to do this stuff is the compiler compliance suite for your chosen compiler.

Breaking compilers is fun. Hopefully something here will help you do it.